# Update all rows with random string every month using mysql

Tags: mysql, random, mysql-event

I am trying to create a mysql event that updates all rows with a random string every month. The string doesn't have to be unique.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `new code`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
??
UPDATE table
SET code = "rand(?)"
```

I have no idea how to do the rest!

Comment: `SET code=SHA(NOW())`

Comment: Cool! Now I got the update function working. How do I make this run every month?

Comment: Make sure event scheduler is enabled https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `MD5` function to convert a random number into a string:

```
SET code = MD5(RAND())
```